# automation script for git cmds

Tags: bash, git, automation

i'm trying to write a bash script that will automate some of the operation that we are doing on daily basic:
1. clone different repos
2. checkout some specific commits
3. compile
4. etc.

my challenge is, that I want this script to be used by different users and I don't want the script to prompt for password for each git cmd.
I thought to get the username + pwd as arguments to the script and then
 git clone https://username:pasword@gitlab.../repoName/usename/proj.git
but I always get an error of "TCP connection reset by peer".
obviously running ssh command or https command without the username builtin working for me fine

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you must use "https" instead "ssh" try with expect script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn git pull
expect "Username"
send "put here your username\r"
expect "Password"
send "put here your password\r"
interact
```

You can use bash and expect in the same script as well.

Comment: thanks, as you can see in my question i'm trying https

Comment: Yes, so use expect script with for example “spawn git clone “https:// gitlab.com/your/repository” instead url with username and password in url - that will do the script.